# Rails 3.2 deployment with Capistrano error when adding Rack::Offline configuration in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano

Before adding it , my deployment was fine ...
I added the following code into routes.rb , running fine in development , but when deploying again on remote server w Capistrano , the deployment is failing :

```
routes.rb
   Workshop::Application.routes.draw do

    if Rails.env.production?
      offline = Rack::Offline.configure :cache_interval => 120 do      
         cache ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("application.css")
         cache ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("application.js")
         # cache other assets
         images = ["favicon.ico", "empty_boxes.png", "isabelle.png", "loading.gif", "errors/not_found.jpg", "errors/access_denied.jpg", "gallery/black.png"]
         images.each do |image|
           cache ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path(image)
          end
         ...
      end 
      ... other routes ..
   end
```

The deployment error is related to any cache action is this bloc :

```
  * executing "cd -- /var/www/vhosts/ceramique-isabelle.fr/rails/workshop/
   releases/2013.... && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production 
    RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile && cp --
  /var/www/vhosts/ceramique-isabelle.fr/rails/workshop/shared/assets/manifest.yml
 /var/www/vhosts/ceramique-isabelle.fr/rails/workshop/releases/2013../assets_manifest.yml"

  servers: ["ceramique-isabelle.fr"]
       [ceramique-isabelle.fr] executing command
       ** [out :: ceramique-isabelle.fr] rake aborted!
        [out :: ceramique-isabelle.fr] application.css isn't precompiled
```

If I suppress some cache lines , then it fails on the following

```
        [out :: ceramique-isabelle.fr] application.js isn't precompiled
         or removing the cache for application.js , it fails on the nex ...
        [out :: ceramique-isabelle.fr] favicon.ico isn't precompiled
```

Is there anyway to avoid this error .. I'll try to deploy wo this block then insert it again and re-deploy again, but I guess it will fails also during the remote server pre-compilayion

Answer (score 1):

It 's not related to this block..... but rather to a css pre-compiling error ...
I tried to pre-compile locally and I got an error

Invalid CSS after "...-border-radius:": expected pseudoclass or pseudoelement, was " 10px;"

going to search where and modify it ....

sorry for bad track